# "Connection reset by peer while reading response header from upstream" error while using PHP(7.4) Exception

Tags: php, nginx, phalcon, fastcgi, fpm

I am getting 502 bad gateway whenever I throw an Exception in `Phalcon 4` application. I am using default PHP `Exception` class that implements `Throwable` interface.

```
throw new Exception ("Some error message here", 500);
```

I wasted so much time and saw all posts about this issue but couldn't find solution for it.

When I check my `nginx` logs it always says

`Connection reset by peer while reading response header from upstream`

Sometimes(15%) it throws the exception and gives me the message but mostly it just shows 502.

I am pretty sure it is not related to my code because if that was the case then it shouldn't even work sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by changing `log_level` to `notice` in `php-fpm.conf` (`etc\php\7.4\fpm`) file:

[image]